Git autocomplete custom command (not arguments after)
I've been trying to add an autocomplete for my custom command, "git extract-unmerged". I'm using git on Windows in git bash through MSYS2 if it matters.
I created a bash script in $HOME/bash_completion.d/git-extract-unmerged.bash which is correctly included to env on shell startup.
It works well for a command arguments after I type "git extract-unmerged <TAB>", but I would like to have autocompletion working if I also type just "git extr<TAB>" and would expect that shell would return "git extract-unmerged ", like it does for built-in git commands.
Is this possible for custom git commands?
I have a hunch that autocompletion of commands is built-in into git.exe and that without modifying the source and recompiling, it is not possible...

So I found one possible solution - define git alias as an alias to itself, i.e. for this case:
git config --global alias.extract-unmerged extract-unmerged

The reason why it works is because in "git-completion.bash", in __git_main(), it will search and compare currently written git command before <TAB>, i.e. "extr" with the output of:
git --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,others,nohelpers,alias,list-complete,config

So if a command is aliased with itself, it will be included in the list, alias will be replaced with the whole command (in this case 1-to-1 replacement), and command autocompleted.
